# Cast Type to Generic

Tags: .net, generics

I have a simple method where I need to pass in a Type variable to another third party method call that is expecting a generic. It works fine if I strongly type the type, but not by passing it in as a parameter.

From what I have read, it looks like this is impossible, especially if high performance is required.

Is this understanding correct?

This works:

```
public IEntity Get(Type type, object objectID)
    {
        if(_store == null) InitDBConnection();
        using (var session = _store?.OpenSession())
        {
            return session?.Load<ContentBlock>(objectID.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This does not:

```
public IEntity Get(Type type, object objectID)
    {
        if(_store == null) InitRavenConnection();
        using (var session = _store?.OpenSession())
        {
            return session?.Load<type>(objectID.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Both generics and reflection are the kind of solutions that work best with similar friends, consider adding a `.Load(Type type, object objectID)` on your session objects as well, otherwise you're going to have to use reflection to invoke this method. Typically with this particular kind of code, which I assume is eventually going to load something off of a database, is that it ends up using reflection to get properties anyway. Basically you're then going from Type to T, and then later from that T back to Type. Both conversions are costly, consider removing the need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoking a generic method via reflection will cost some performance but it is possible.

To do:

```
var result = session.Load<Entity>("abc");
```

with reflection looks like:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Session).GetMethod("Load");
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Entity));
var result = generic.Invoke(session, new[] { "abc" });
```

which as you have mentioned is a lot slower (over 20 times slower on my PC).

You can improve the performance by only doing the hard work once and caching the results of reflecting over the type using something like this:

```
public class SessionInvoker
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Func<Session, string, IEntity>> cache =
        new Dictionary<Type, Func<Session, string, IEntity>>();

    public IEntity Invoke(Type type, Session session, string id)
    {
        var invoker = cache.ContainsKey(type)
            ? cache[type]
            : CreateAndCache(type);

        return invoker(session, id);
    }

    private Func<Session, string, IEntity> CreateAndCache(Type type)
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Session).GetMethod("Load");
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        var invoker = new Func<Session, string, IEntity>((session, id) => 
            (IEntity)generic.Invoke(session, new[] { id }));
        cache[type] = invoker;
        return invoker;
    }
}
```

Which is about 4 times slower on my PC than calling the method directly:

```
var result = invoker.Invoke(type, session, "abc");
```

---

Here's the code for getting the timings:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var session = new Session();
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            var result = session.Load<Entity>("abc");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            MethodInfo method = typeof(Session).GetMethod("Load");
            MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Entity));
            var result = generic.Invoke(session, new[] { "abc" });
        }
        Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        MethodInfo method2 = typeof(Session).GetMethod("Load");
        MethodInfo generic2 = method2.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Entity));
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            var result = generic2.Invoke(session, new[] { "abc" });
        }
        Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var invoker = new SessionInvoker();
        var type = typeof(Entity);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            var result = invoker.Invoke(type, session, "abc");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public interface IEntity { }

    public class Entity : IEntity { }

    public class Session
    {
        public IEntity Load<T>(string id) where T : IEntity, new()
        {
            return new T();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this was pretty much where I got to. even a x4 speed reduction is too much, so will have to do it the long way